# Find out if device has rebooted/crashed without BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to know if the device has crashed or rebooted and would like to avoid using a `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

Is that possible? I was thinking of reading out the uptime and compare it (how do I read it out?) Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the uptime will only help you when they have started the app "earlier" than last time (as you already know). You can read the uptime using [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) if you want to go down that path anyway.

An alternative solution, although untested, is to read:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
```

This file will contain a uuid that will be different on every restart.